# Get symbol from goto case in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to get Symbol for label from GotoStatementSyntax, below code works for labeled statements, but not for case labels:

```
    public override void VisitGotoStatement(GotoStatementSyntax node)
    {
        var symbol = Model.GetSymbolInfo(node.Expression).Symbol;
    }
```

I found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99c31a6a-6fde-4ecc-b7be-d53bee88a7da/retrieve-referenced-labelsymbol-of-gotostatementsyntax?forum=roslyn) that is was not supported in 2012. Is it still the case or there is a way to get a symbol from goto case statement?

Comment: Case labels aren't goto statements though. Can you clarify exactly what pieces of code you have in mind?

Comment: @jeroen-vannevel switch (i) { case 1: goto case 2; case 2: goto default; default: break; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two ways of getting the labeled statements.

1. You can use the [`SemanticModel.LookupLabels`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/SemanticModel.cs,594) method to get the associated label symbol. Finding out the correct name parameter is a bit tricky though:

   ```
   var name = node.CaseOrDefaultKeyword.ValueText != null
       ? string.Join(" ", new[] { node.CaseOrDefaultKeyword.Text, node.Expression?.ToString() }.Where(x => x != null)) +  ":" 
       : node.Expression.ToString();
   var label = Model.LookupLabels(node.SpanStart, name).OfType<ILabelSymbol>().SingleOrDefault();
   ```
2. A `GotoStatementSyntax` resolves to an [`IBranchStatement`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/IStatement.cs,353) operation, which contains a reference to the targeted label symbol:

   ```
   var label = ((IBranchStatement)Model.GetOperation(node)).Target;
   ```

Both code snippets give you the same `ILabelSymbol`.

Here's the LinqPad script I used to repro the question:

```
async Task Test()
{
    var ws = new AdhocWorkspace();
    var proj = ws.AddProject("test", "C#");
    var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(@"
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var i = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1: goto case 2;
            case 2: goto default;
            case 3: goto wat;
            default: break;
        }
wat:
        return;
    }
}");
    var root = tree.GetRoot();
    var doc = proj.AddDocument("file1.cs", root);
    proj = doc.Project.AddMetadataReference(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));

    var compilation = await proj.GetCompilationAsync();
    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

    var walker = new Walker { Model = model };
    walker.Visit(root);
}

class Walker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public SemanticModel Model { get; set; }

    public override void VisitGotoStatement(GotoStatementSyntax node)
    {
        var name = node.CaseOrDefaultKeyword.ValueText != null
            ? string.Join(" ", new[] { node.CaseOrDefaultKeyword.Text, node.Expression?.ToString() }.Where(x => x != null)) +  ":"
            : node.Expression.ToString();
        var label = Model.LookupLabels(node.SpanStart, name).OfType<ILabelSymbol>().SingleOrDefault();

        var label2 = ((IBranchStatement)Model.GetOperation(node)).Target;
        // (label == label2).Dump();

        base.VisitGotoStatement(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late accept, was not able to run it straight away and had to switch to another project temporary. I had to use prerelease version of roslyn 2 to make GetOperation to work. Looks like I could completely switch from syntax nodes to operations in current project. My test project - https://github.com/isanych/so-38724403